# Html5 canvas loading images with JCanvasScript

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas, load

hello guys I want to load multiple images with JCanvasScript in html5 canvas, but I can't do it. I want to load images side by side in each row. for that I have function loadx(numX, numY) numX - is number of images in a row and numY is number of rows. for example loadX(5,4) or loadX(10,3) is giving me the same result only 1 image.

here is a code

```
    <script>
        function init(){
            loadx(5, 4);
        }

        function loadx(numX, numY){
            var numTotal = numX * numY;
            var imgBMPs = [];
            var sliceImg = new Image();
            sliceImg.src = "abstract.jpg";
            var sliceBmp;
            var imgBmp = [];
            imgBmp['width'] = sliceImg.width / numX;
            imgBmp['height'] = sliceImg.height / numY;
            imgBmp['row'] = 0;
            imgBmp['y'] = 0;

            sliceImg.onload = function(){
                for (i = 0; i < numY; i++){
                imgBmp['y'] = i * imgBmp['height'];
                    for (a = 0; a < numX; a++){
                        jc.start('canvas');
                        imgBmp = new jc.image(sliceImg, a * imgBmp['width'], imgBmp['y'], imgBmp['width'], imgBmp['height']);
                        imgBMPs.push(imgBmp);
                        jc.start('canvas');
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

when I tried to debug the code I found out something:

after this

```
              sliceImg.onload = function(){
                    for (i = 0; i < numY; i++){
                    imgBmp['y'] = i * imgBmp['height'];
```

I added the code

```
alert (imgBmp['height']);
```

and when I refreshed the page First result was the number but other were "Undefined" so what is wrong?

Comment: What were the results of any debugging you did?

Comment: @Hidde I updated my post. Please see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your inner for loop you're reassigning the variable `imgBmp` to an instance of `js.image`. This means that the properties of the original object are lost by the time the loop iterates the second time.

Try updating your code as follows:

```
<script>
    function init(){
        loadx(5, 4);
    }

    function loadx(numX, numY){
        var numTotal = numX * numY;
        var imgBMPs = [];
        var sliceImg = new Image();
        sliceImg.src = "abstract.jpg";
        var sliceBmp;


        /*
           // imgBmp is being used as an object not an array 
           // so the following syntax is usually preferred
           var imgBmp = {
               width: sliceImg.width / numx,
               height: sliceImg.height / numy
           }

           // and to retrieve a property:
           console.log(imgBmp.width);
        */

        var imgBmp = [];
        imgBmp['width'] = sliceImg.width / numX;
        imgBmp['height'] = sliceImg.height / numY;
        imgBmp['row'] = 0;
        imgBmp['y'] = 0;

        sliceImg.onload = function(){
            for (i = 0; i < numY; i++){
            imgBmp['y'] = i * imgBmp['height'];
                for (a = 0; a < numX; a++){
                    jc.start('canvas');
                    // create a new variable to hold the instance of jc.image
                    // so the original object reference is preserved 
                    var jcImage = new jc.image(sliceImg, a * imgBmp['width'], imgBmp['y'], imgBmp['width'], imgBmp['height']);
                    imgBMPs.push(jcImage);                        
                    //imgBmp = new jc.image(sliceImg, a * imgBmp['width'], imgBmp['y'], imgBmp['width'], imgBmp['height']);
                    //imgBMPs.push(imgBmp);
                    jc.start('canvas');
                }

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```